# Feeding data into RNN in tensorflow with Convolutional Neural Network as feature extractor

Tags: tensorflow, batch-processing, pipeline, convolution, recurrent-neural-network

I have a convolutional neural network of 3 layers followed with a dense layer and finally, a softmax layer. The purpose is to train the convolutional layers, then replace the dense layer with an RNN layer. My problem is, I need a **batch_size** of **128**, number of **time_steps** of **100**, and **hidden_state** size of 100. Therefore, any input has to be of shape: **[batch_size, n_steps, number_features]**, where the number_features is the reshaped pool layer after the 3rd conv layer.

So, feeding `128 (for batch_size) * 100(for num_steps)` images will not fit into my memory.

What I need to achieve is the follows: I need to process 128 images at a time, as a mini-batch, extract their features, then *hold on*. After 100 mini-batches, I can feed the 128, 100, num_features into the RNN. In this case, I will not run out of memory.

So, how can I achieve this in tensorflow?

Any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: Should be doable with [control dependencies](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Graph#control_dependencies): the RNN gets a control dependency on all of the preprocessing having finished, and each preprocessing mini-batch gets a control dependency on the previous.

Comment: @AllenLavoie, I'm sure about your method. Can you please share a code. Thanks!!